# bezierPath setfill with diff colours Not Working ( to create a mountain climb color coding )

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, drawrect

My goal is to create a chart much like below. Where the diff colours represent the different slope / gradient % for each segment.

[image]

My previous code, I have already managed to get the "mountain" outline, now further improved it such that I am now making a set of "boxes" which represents each colour segment. But am facing some issue.

Here is the code I'm using right now.

```
    let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
    let nextPt = fillSlopes(at: idx)

    if idx > 0 {
      let prevPt = fillSlopes(at: idx - 1)
      myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: height))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: prevPt.y))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: nextPt.x, y: nextPt.y))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: nextPt.x, y: height))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: height))

      myBezier.close()
      // This is test code, actual code will compare current slope % 
      // (in an array) and then based on the slope %, will change
      // the colour accordingly.
      if idx % 2 == 0 {
        UIColor.systemRed.setFill()
        myBezier.fill()
      } else {
        UIColor.systemBlue.setFill()
        myBezier.fill()
      }
```

This is the results. Unfortunately, the colours is not coming out properly.  What Am I missing?

[image]

In addition to this, Drawing so many little boxes is really eating up a lot of CPU cycles, if there are other suggestions to get the desired output result is also appreciated. Thanks

Update:
Many Thanks for @seaspell, I realised what was happening. I was putting my `let myBezier = UIBezierPath()` outside of the `for` loop hence my `[UIBezierPath]` array was getting mangled up. eg:

This got things all wrong:

```
func xxx { 
  let myBezier = UIBezierPath() // <<<<<< this is wrong
      
  for idx in slopeBars.indices { 
      // do stuff 
  }
```

This is Correct and fixed some performance issue as well:

```
func xxx { 
  var slopeBars = [UIBezierPath]()
  var slopeBarColorArray = [UIColor]()

  for idx in slopeBars.indices { 
    let myBezier = UIBezierPath()  // <<<<< Moved here
    let nextPt = fillSlopes(at: idx)

    if idx > 0 {
      let prevPt = fillSlopes(at: idx - 1)
      myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: height))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: prevPt.y))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: nextPt.x, y: nextPt.y))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: nextPt.x, y: height))
      myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: prevPt.x, y: height))

      myBezier.close()
      slopeBars.append(myBezier)

        if gradient < 0.0 {
          slopeBarColorArray.append(UIColor(cgColor: Consts.elevChart.slope0_0))
        } else if gradient < 4.0 {
          slopeBarColorArray.append(UIColor(cgColor: Consts.elevChart.slope0_4))
       }

    for i in 0..<slopeBars.count {
      if !slopeBarColorArray.isEmpty {
        slopeBarColorArray[i].setStroke()
        slopeBarColorArray[i].setFill()
      }
    
      slopeBars[i].stroke()
      slopeBars[i].fill()
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I see you have the ui looking good. It looks like your still calling a func for building from draw(rect:) though. Personally, I don't recommend doing any work from there. But, if you're happy with the performance I guess you're ok. If it gets to be a problem, take a look at just building the bars and then just enumerate and color them in draw.

Comment: @SeaSpell yeah. Currently it's set up in that manner as I'm sending the datapoints to the ```UIView``` from the main VC and doing the ```buildbars```. Right now there's little performance penalty (that I can see) but will definitely revisit or refactor in the future. (dread the big rewrite :-p) One thing which is helping is that I'm striding the number of bars instead of plotting it full 1000 points etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with using bezier paths for this. You need to use a new one for each bar though and also you don't want to build them in draw(rect:). I suspect that is the cause of the CPU issues.

Take a look at this example I put together.

```
   class BarChartView: UIView {

    lazy var dataPoints: [CGFloat] = {
        var points = [CGFloat]()
        for _ in 1...barCount {
            let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(bounds.maxY / 2))
            points.append(CGFloat(random))
        }
        return points
    }()

    var bars = [UIBezierPath]()
    private let barCount = 20

    lazy var colors: [UIColor] = {
        let colors:  [UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .cyan, .brown, .darkGray, .green, .yellow, .gray, .lightGray, .magenta, .orange, .purple, .systemPink, .white]
        var random = [UIColor]()

        for i in 0...barCount {
            random.append(colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))])
        }

        return random
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.bars = buildBars()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.bars = buildBars()
    }


    func buildBars() -> [UIBezierPath] {

        let lineWidth = Int(bounds.maxX / CGFloat(barCount))

        var bars = [UIBezierPath]()

        for i in 0..<barCount {

            let line = UIBezierPath()

            let leftX = lineWidth * i
            let rightX = leftX + lineWidth
            let centerX = leftX + (lineWidth / 2)

            let nextLeftPoint = (i == 0 ? dataPoints[i] : dataPoints[i - 1])
            let nextRightPoint = (i == barCount - 1 ? dataPoints[i] : dataPoints[i + 1])

            let currentPoint = dataPoints[i]


            //bottom left
            line.move(to:  CGPoint(x: leftX, y: Int(bounds.maxY)) )
            //bottom right
            line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rightX, y: Int(bounds.maxY)) )

            //top right
            line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rightX,  y: Int((currentPoint + nextRightPoint) / 2)) )

            //top center
            line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: centerX, y: Int(currentPoint)) )

            //top left
            line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: leftX,  y: Int((currentPoint + nextLeftPoint) / 2)) )

            //close the path
            line.close()

            bars.append(line)
        }

        return bars
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        for i in 0..<bars.count {
            colors[i].setStroke()
            colors[i].setFill()

            bars[i].stroke()
            bars[i].fill()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, TQ. the example, did you test that code in playgrounds or something? Tried putting it into my existing UIView IBOutlet but it didn't stick. Anyways, I called it using BarChartView.init() and looked at the output. So basically, we're still doing ```draw(rect)``` but only difference is the loop to make the lines/bars are done **outside** of drawrect and only passing the result ```bars``` array to ```draw(rect)```

Comment: One more - you're using the ```linewidth``` to draw the bars instead of making a box and filling the colour. I didn't think of that, cos I figured the top won't be flat. (top would have a diff point between y1 and y2) due to slope. Can this work?

Comment: You can still draw your slopes how you want. I just made a simple example of how you should implement drawing. Anytime you override draw(frame: ) there is a performance cost. Even an empty override will have costs. You should do all your work somewhere else and only use draw rect for drawing. Line width will only be even lines on top so you'll have to implement the bezier paths you want to show.

Comment: Also not I set fill and stroke in draw rect. This must be done there.

Comment: Took some head scratching but check out the updated sample. I think that's what you're looking for. Also did you forget to set the class in storyboard. It works with storyboards for me.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right, I did forget to set the class in storyboard. Once I did that, the coloured bars came out. The ```top centre``` code looks interesting as well. Nice twist tho I'm unsure if needed in my case, but interesting none-the-less. your solution definitely helped me see things in another perspective. I need to move more code out of ```draw(rect)``` (now my calc are being done entirely there)